# Sram AXS derailleur does not shift

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, sram, shifting, axs

Have you encountered a problem where a rear AXS derailleur stops shifting? Any suggestions?

I bought a mint 2023 GX AXS derailleur on Marketplace, it worked for the first short test ride on a road but then stopped shifting. The seller did not have the original receipt so no warranty. The battery is brand new and fully charged. Symptoms:

- when I shift, the light on the derailleur blinks green and the SRAM app shows that the gear has changed but the derailleur does not move;
- when I do micro adjustments in the SRAM app, it only changes the number on the app but the derailleur does not do anything.

Derailleur info:
Model: RD-GX-1E-A1
Firmware Version: 2.46.5

Attempts fix:

- re-plugging the battery did not help;
- holding the AXS button and re-plugging the battery did not help;
- updating to the latest firmware did not help;
- I found this video and tried to do the same thing: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ynJG_l0M0bg. This does not seem to help or maybe I am missing the point of what the author is actually fixing on this video. I cleaned and lubed the internal gear wheels but it did not help.

Observations after disassembling the derailleur:

- when all internal pinion gears are put, the motor starts spinning only sometimes when I connect the battery but more often it does not;
- when I remove one gear to let the motor to spin freely, it always spins when connecting the battery.

Perhaps the problem is in that safety mechanism that disengages the main motor when the derailleur is being hit.

I can barely find any info on fixing SRAM derailleurs, any help will be very appreciated.

[image]

[image]